# windows phone 8 old map vs new map

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8, bing-maps, here-api

I have a two WP8 projects. This is projects with map. First project with new `Nokia maps` and second project with old `Bing maps`. I noticed inappropriate behavior of old maps. They consume large amounts of memory, and when I go away from the maps then the memory is not freed. In WP7 `Bing maps` behave differently, it spent as much RAM memory, but when I go away from the map, the memory is immediately freed. How can I return the memory, I have a big problem with old maps, I exceed the limit of 90 Mb in my project ..

Screenshots below.

Any help.

Thanks in advance!

**Project 1 Nokia Maps**

[image: MainPage]

[image: Memory usage]

[image: Map page]

[image]

After go away from map

[image]

**Project 2 Old Bing maps**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After go away from map

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if this could be help you but I found this

FYI: For Windows Phone 8 map control you need to use the TileSource class from Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.  (i.e. Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.TileSource)

here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/66512153-06d0-4269-996a-b4b7e5f995de/windows-phone-8-api-for-open-street-map-osm

Comment: Wow! Thanks it's interesting for me!

Comment: if my answer is ok you can choose as answer, or post me the solution, i'm interesting in too:)

Answer (score 0):

You can display static maps, use Jeff Wilcox library for such purpose. Check it here http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/jeffwilcox-maps/.

Comment: thank you, I'm familiar with that component, it does not fit me, I show on the map in real-time movement of multiple users