# Using Google maps in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, windows-phone-8, bing-maps, here-api

It's possible using Google maps in Windows Phone 8? The question may seem strange, since the internet is very much a post about it. But in practice, I was faced with real problems.

The only way I know to use Google maps (with MapTileLayer.TileSources) is described in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153467/Google-Maps-for-Windows-Phone-7-using-Bing-Map-Con). But you can not replace the tiles in the new map control  in WP 8. Of course we can use the old map contol plugging the appropriate library. This is where I have problems begin.

The old Bing Map control in WP8 has a memory leak, and using them is not possible. Perhaps more accurately, but over time will be a huge memory consumption. I do not know how to fix it. I wrote about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876001/windows-phone-8-old-map-vs-new-map) and [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/bingmaps/feedback/details/783257/windows-phone-8-bing-maps-memory-leak). In the end, I do not see a way to use the Google maps in own WP8 app. If someone successfully use Google maps in WP8 application, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you can use Google Maps tiles inside the control, you won't be authorize to do so. Google Maps terms of use specify that you cannot direct access tiles or other resources out of the official control. So technically it's possible but legally you cannot.
So based on the terms of use, you can use the Google Maps control (JavaScript API) or use another mobile control (which won't be compatible with WP8).

Comment: Hi @NicolasBoonaert! Sorry for the late answer. Do you mean, that I can't publish my app with Google maps tiles in Microsoft store?

Comment: Except if you're using the JavaScript API (which might have problems with WP8), you are no allowed to access Google Maps resources out of the provided APIs.

Comment: @NicolasBoonaert please add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you can use Google Maps tiles inside the control, you won't be authorize to do so.

Google Maps terms of use specify that you cannot direct access tiles or other resources out of the official control.

So technically it's possible but legally you cannot. So based on the terms of use, you can use the Google Maps control (JavaScript API) or use another mobile control (which won't be compatible with WP8).

Answer (score 0):

There is an app in the WP Store, called gMaps, that uses Google Maps. Do you think that it's made with the JavaScript API?

Comment: No, but developers risked when published application. They did not know about all the nuances of the license agreement. There are many restrictions, but there are exceptions. Developers gMaps posted in detail about all the difficulties (in Russian, if interested can translate) here http://habrahabr.ru/post/126398/

Comment: See this comment in English about exceptions http://habrahabr.ru/post/126398/#comment_4164905

Comment: Yes, but the things remains regarding the Bing Maps control that does not allow to load competitors' content inside it. So both platforms are posing problem regarding the licensing.