# Google Maps for Cordova

Tags: html, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am planning to integrate google map feature for my Hybrid Mobile Application.
This is targeted for Android,iOS and Windows.

```
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps
```

Above cordova plugin only works for iOS and Android, what about windows phone ? Do I need to use deparate Javascript Web API's of google maps to integrate with Windows phone ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't build this yet before, what can I provide you is some tutorials and different threads.

Like the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927274/using-google-maps-in-windows-phone-8), what you want to achieve is technically possible, but it is not legal. So basically you need a 3rd party app for these to work.

You can use Bing Map Control to use Google Maps in Windows. This tutorial explains everything with sample code and screenshot for you to follow.

For more information check this link:

- [Windows Phone Doesn't Support Google Maps Because Google Doesn't Want It To](http://mashable.com/2013/01/05/google-maps-windows-phone/#hPbB5j8vnuqS)
- [Getting Start With Google Map in Windows Phone 7](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd3310/starting-with-google-map-in-windows-7-phone-application/)